# Rim width and minimum tyre width?

Tags: tire, rims

I have a set of two rims which have an inner width of 24mm, both of them are  hooked. It is unclear after looking around various sources if Continental Grand Prix 5000 in 32-622 might fit or may have problems. The pamphlet it came with doesn't specify the maximum/minimum tyre width.

[image]
(This rim width marked here is 24mm)

Are they a security hazard or will they be fine?

Comment: Can I suggest changing "internal diameter" to "internal width".

Comment: You are absolutely correct!

Comment: Have a look at this answer to a similar question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/59104/30402

Comment: MioBambino, @DavidW pointed out in chat that the question we linked as a duplicate is specifc to tubless ready rims. The tyre you mentioned (GP5000) comes also as a tubeless tyre. Conti tyres are also notoriously tight on rims. In this specific case Mavic's table from the linked answer might help you. But if that is not the case, say so in the comments and I shall request to reopen this question. I am sorry, for voting for close prematurely.